# Solr doesn't show accurate results for E-Commerce data

Tags: solr

I am trying to integrate Apache Solr in e-commerce data. There is some issue with search, it doesn't show accurate results. Here is the search outcome against **"Apple iPhone 11 128GB (PTA Approved)"**

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":4,
    "params":{
      "q":"Apple iPhone 11 128GB (PTA Approved)",
      "df":"product_name",
      "fl":"product_name, score"}},
  "response":{"numFound":560,"start":0,"maxScore":2.3723078,"docs":[
      {
        "product_name":"Apple iPhone XR 128GB Black - PTA Complaint",
        "score":2.3723078},
      {
        "product_name":"Apple | iPhone 11 - 128GB",
        "score":2.2690601}
    ]
  }}
```

I think the search engine ignores the (iPhone **11**) keyword and gives more priority to **PTA**. So I tried with the negative boost to the PTA keyword and it shows good results.

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":3,
    "params":{
      "q":"Apple iPhone 11 128GB (PTA Approved)",
      "defType":"edismax",
      "df":"product_name",
      "fl":"product_name, score",
      "stopwords":"true",
      "bq":"(*:* -PTA)^0.4"}},
  "response":{"numFound":560,"start":0,"maxScore":2.6690602,"docs":[
      {
        "product_name":"Apple | iPhone 11 - 128GB",
        "score":2.6690602},
      {
        "product_name":"Apple iPhone XR 128GB Black - PTA Complaint",
        "score":2.3723078}
]
  }}
```

I thought it would be fine if I pass the PTA negative boost with each Query, but again it doesn't work when I added the color in the search term. **Apple iPhone 11 128GB Black (PTA Approved)**

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":6,
    "params":{
      "q":"Apple iPhone 11 128GB Black (PTA Approved)",
      "defType":"edismax",
      "df":"product_name",
      "fl":"product_name, score",
      "stopwords":"true",
      "bq":"(*:* -PTA)^0.4"}},
  "response":{"numFound":560,"start":0,"maxScore":3.6262395,"docs":[
      {
        "product_name":"Apple iPhone XR 128GB Black - PTA Complaint",
        "score":3.6262395},
      {
        "product_name":"Apple | iPhone 11 - 128GB",
        "score":2.6690602}
      ]
  }}
```

Now I can't add a negative boost for the thousands of colors. Can someone please suggest me a better way to achieve accurate results?

Note I am using StandardTokenizerFactory for **product_name** field. I have also removed the repetitive results in the result to make it simplified. Thanks

Comment: Is the rule that you want to give `11` more weight instead? If that's the goal, wouldn't it be better to give that term a higher boost? How do you know that "11" is an important term? In general you'd put those terms in a different field and then give that field a large boost with `qf`, such as a `model_name` field instead.

Comment: That's the issue I can't boost "11" as there are other models as well like iPhone 8, XS, etc. I think there is something missing on my side like tokenizer strategy. My concern is why the search engine ignores "11" and gives priority to XR ..!

Comment: It does not ignore `11` - your result with `11` is included. Both `11` and `PTA` is in your query, and both results have one of each term (so they both contribute to the score). The number of documents containing `PTA` is probably lower than `11`, and this makes `PTA` contribute a higher score, since it's a more seldom term in your index (this is the tf/idf part of the scoring formula (although modified to bm25 these days, the concept is still the same). The question then becomes _what_ metric do you want to use to score one higher than the other? What's the rule you have in your head?

Comment: You can also append `debug=all` to your query to see exactly how the score is calculated for each document.

Comment: I want to give high priority to product model (iPhone 11), brand (Apple), but less priority to colors, PTA, Approved Warranty keywords.

Comment: You are right it doesn't ignore the 11, as I added more products to the dataset it shows more relevant results. should I make the list of less priority of keywords?

Comment: You're going to need more semantics in your document - add those terms that describe the model to a separate `model_name` field, then give that field a higher boost so it contributes more to the score. If you don't have any semantics behind your documents so you can express what's important, Solr can't magically determine what you're thinking as relevant terms.